# MVC List Error List<Model>

Tags: c#

I'm using foreach to transfer data from list to another but when adding value updated automatically to last value added. For example:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = new List<Model>()

foreach(var item in list1) {
   list2.Add(item)
}

the result in list2 is [ 3, 3, 3]
```

Actually example is below :

```
var _sizes = new List<ProductsSize>();
var _size = new ProductsSize();

if (model.Dynamic_ProductsSize.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in model.Dynamic_ProductsSize)
    {
        _size.SizeId = item;
        _sizes.Add(_size);
    }
}
model.ProductsSize = _sizes.ToList();
```

I need to know why it only takes the last item and what is the solution for this case

Comment: Because you are adding the same object each time. You need to declare `var _size = new ProductsSize();` inside the `foreach` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have *one* `ProductsSize` object:

```
var _size = new ProductsSize();
```

And you keep modifying that same object.  All references to that object, including any list elements it's been added to, get updated when you modify that *one* object.

Instead, create your new object in the loop:

```
foreach (var item in model.Dynamic_ProductsSize)
{
    var _size = new ProductsSize();
    _size.SizeId = item;
    _sizes.Add(_size);
}
```

That way each element in the list is a *new* object instead of the same object added multiple times.

---

Side note, you have a few things in the code which aren't necessary.  Checking the length before the loop, for example, as well as converting a list to a list at the end.

In fact, I imagine *all of the code shown* can be shortened to simply this:

```
model.ProductsSize = model.Dynamic_ProductsSize.Select(p => new ProductsSize { SizeId = p }).ToList();
```

In which case you're also just converting one model property to another model property.  Why not put this logic in the model itself and skip the whole thing?

```
public IEnumerable<ProductsSize> ProductsSize
{
    get { return this.Dynamic_ProductsSize.Select(p => new ProductsSize { SizeId = p });
}
```

Unless there's a particular reason you want the same data twice in two different properties that isn't clear from this code, having one set of data and just different views/calculations/etc. of that data is often preferred.

Comment: It should also be noted that the `ToList()` call at the end (`model.ProductsSize = _sizes.ToList();`) is completely unnecessary

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Indeed.  As is the check for `if (model.Dynamic_ProductsSize.Count > 0)`.  And the loop body itself can be shortened to one line.  Now that I think about it, all of the code shown can be just a single LINQ projection...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object before adding it to the list. You can use the object initializer syntax to keep it concise:

```
 if (model.Dynamic_ProductsSize.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in model.Dynamic_ProductsSize)
    {
        _sizes.Add(new ProductsSize(){SizeId = item});
    }
}
```